# how to do or operations with django rest framework search-filter instead of and operation on query parameters

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filter

here is my code.

```
class op_ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet) :
    http_method_names = ['get']
    queryset = Op.objects.all().filter()
    serializer_class = op_Serializer
    pagination_class = MyPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend , SearchFilter , OrderingFilter]
    filter_class = op_filter
    search_fields = ['website' , 'title' , 'description' , 'organization__name']
```

search_fields search for keywords in the website, title, description, and organization column of a table.

this is how I sent the postman request.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?search=Belgian,Services
```

right now my code performs an end operation. it returns me those rows which contain both the Belgian, Services keywords whereas I want that it returns those rows which contain only Belgian, only services, or both of them in any of its 4 columns I provided on search-fields.

how can I achieve it?

your help is much appreciated.
I tried this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56097041/how-to-filter-data-in-drf-from-database-by-multiple-keywords) but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you want some kind of "OR" search filter ("both of them" is included in "belgian in any fields or (xor ?) services in any fields").

You should try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57692302/5743955) with a small modification:

```py
query = query | Q(website__contains=term) | Q(title__contains=term) | Q(description__contains=term) | Q(organization__name__contains=term)
```